# Parse a line in Java

Tags: java

```
String line = "a:b:c:d"   // Valid
```

In the above line , I have 4 values separated by 3 ":".

```
Sting invalidLine = "a:b:c" //Invalid
```

As 4th value is missing

```
String invalidLine = "a:b:c:"  //Invalid
```

As 4th value is missing .

I want to spit it the line on count ofdelimiter ":".

Comment: http://www.google.lk/search?q=split+string+in+java&aq=0&oq=split+string+&sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8

Comment: split the string with ":" to an array and find the length of array.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Nice and easy, just use:

```
String[] stringValidTokens = line.split(":");
```

Gives you a String array which you can compare to the invalid string array, either by iterating or by checking number of items to check if valid or not.... or do whatever you like with it.

So to compare both strings do something like:

```
boolean valid = false;
String[] stringValidTokens = line.split(":");
String[] stringinValidTokens = invalidline.split(":");
if(stringValidTokens.size() == stringInvalidTokens.size()){
valid = true;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

*I want to spit it the line on count ofdelimiter ":".*

This code is splitting the given string on count of ofdelimiter ":"

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    String line = "a:b:c:d";
    int count = line.length() - line.replace(":", "").length();
    System.out.println(count);
    String[] str = null;
    if (count == 3) {
        str = line.split(":");
        System.out.println(Arrays.toString(str));
        if (Arrays.asList(str).contains("") || str.length < 4)
            System.out.println("Invalid");
    } else {
        
        System.out.println("Invalid");
    }

}
```